# Why can't you use Scriptable Objects in Mirror?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

In my Network Behavior script, I am trying to use a Scriptable Object(Block) to get a prefab to Instantiate. I have this function.

```
[Command(requiresAuthority = false)]
private void InstiniateBlock(Vector2 blockPos,Block bl)
{

    GameObject Stone =GameObject.Instantiate(bl.prefab, blockPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), null);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(Stone);
}
```

Whenever I run it i get this error

```
Disconnecting connId=0 to prevent exploits from an Exception in MessageHandler: ArgumentException The Object you want to instantiate is null.
```

I have made sure that the Scriptable Object has a prefab and that the prefab is in spawn prefabs with a Network Identity. Can you help please?

Comment: Do you actually have values set for it? Does your NetworkBehavior script actually point to the ScriptableObject? Does the ScriptableObject actually have something set for the `.prefab` field? `The Object you want to instantiate is null.` should be a pretty big hint here I think.

Comment: yes, the Scriptable object has a prefab and that it points to the scriptableObject

Comment: I would split the operation into pieces then, with debug statements, and see what exactly is triggering the error. You're trying to instantiate something that's null but you're referencing two things at once there, `bl` and `.prefab`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `[SyncVar]` on the "bl" scriptable Object? i was having the same problem using SyncVar, if you are using SyncVar, you can identify items by their ID (like guid) and load them as an alternative to SyncVar
(i'm assuming that you are using SyncVar)

Here is My Approach:
(you would do something using the `[Command]` and `[ClientRPC]` attributes passing the ID so then you can load the scriptable object directly since GameObject are NOT serializable)

```
public ItemClass currentItem;
[...]
public ItemClass GetItemByID(string id)
    {
       // i put my ScripableObject on the resources folder
        ItemClass[] items = Resources.LoadAll<ItemClass>("Items/Data");
        foreach(ItemClass i in items)
        {
            if(i.id == id)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```